# Extract "|" from a character in R

Tags: r

This is my character vector:

```
mycharacter<-"    Directors:Chris Renaud, Yarrow Cheney                 |     Stars:Louis C.K., Eric Stonestreet, Kevin Hart, Lake Bell    "
```

Why I cant extract the `"|"` from my character?

Also, after extract `"|"` how can I build a data frame with two columns. One being Directors and other being Stars?

Any help?

Comment: `gsub("\\|","",mycharacter)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub`:

```
 # return the left side of |
 gsub("^(.*)\\|(.*)$","\\1",mycharacter)
 [1] "    Directors:Chris Renaud, Yarrow Cheney                 "

 # return the right side of |
 gsub("^(.*)\\|(.*)$","\\2",mycharacter)
 [1] "     Stars:Louis C.K., Eric Stonestreet, Kevin Hart, Lake Bell    "
```

If you want to remove the spaces you can act on the regular expression `(.*)`.

```
director <- gsub("^\\s+(.*)\\|(.*)$","\\1",mycharacter)
director <- gsub("\\s+$","",director)

star <- gsub("^(.*)\\|\\s+(.*)$","\\2",mycharacter)
star <- gsub("\\s+$","",star)
```

You can then build a `data.frame` with

```
 myDF <- data.frame(Directors = director, Stars= star)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `fixed` as the `|` in default mode in regex is a metacharacter suggesting `OR`.  So, if we want to get the literal value, use `fixed` or escape (`\\`) or place it inside square brackets

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(mycharacter, fixed("|"))
```